# How to image stream to Android Surface by OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm confused with Android ***Surface***. According to [its document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface), I could understand *Surface* is a producer and *SurfaceTexture* is a consumer. And it seems there're examples passing SurfaceTexture to Camera or to MediaPlayer. I assume they (i.e., Camera & MediaPlayer) internally image stream to *SurfaceTexture*(i.e. consumer) through *Surface*(i.e. producer). But I could not find any example showing how OpenGL directly image stream to *Surface*, though the document says OpenGL also can be producer-side. Here, I'm assuming a flow like "texture drawn by OpenGL -> *Surface* -> *SurfaceTexture*".

I'm asking this question because I'm making an app that does offscreen rendering using OpenGL FBO and needs to copy the rendered result (i.e. output in the form of texture) to multiple *SurfaceTexture* destinations.

I guess I misunderstood something. I'd appreciate if anybody can correct me.

Comment: Unclear if you've seen: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture and https://github.com/google/grafika